# Need to validate MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt in Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

I need to validate a date string in a specific format in Javascript.

The format is: MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt

I'm having a really hard time trying to find either a date library that will handle it, or a regex function that will do the same.

I've tried Date.js, which is close, but has the following problem:

```
date.parseExact('10/21/2011 06:00 AM', ['MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt']); //passes
date.parseExact('10/21/2011 06:00 A', ['MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt']); //passes
```

That second one should not pass.

Does anyone know of a Regex that could satisfy this need, or perhaps am I using the Date.js library wrong?  Any help would be appreciated, I've been banging my head against the wall for the better part of 2 hours.

Comment: Is there any harm in simply treating the second form as valid?  It is very unlikely that it means anything else.

Comment: 1) What's the reason for not allowing the second form? (As you can see, date parsing eats it just fine) 2) Where is the input coming from? 3) Will checking the length of the string suffice?

Comment: This is a date-time format that is used throughout an extensive legacy application, and it's what the users are used to.  This date gets converted from a string to a date in an Oracle update statement, and its date conversion is much less forgiving, it requires that exact format.

Comment: This isn't exactly related, but make sure you're not making any dangerous assumptions about time zones. (Since that's not included in this format.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to validate that it is an actual date, or just that it follows that exact format? If just the format, you can use this regex:

```
/[0-1]\d\/[0-3]\d\/\d{4} [0-1]\d:[0-5]\d [aApP][mM]/
```

You could use Date.js in combination with the above regex to validate that it is a valid date, and matches your exact format. Examples:

```
01/01/9999 01:00 AM - matches
12/31/9999 01:59 PM - matches
99/99/9999 99:99 AM - no match (day/month out of range)
12/31/9999 99:59 PM - no match (hours out of range)
01/01/9999 99:99 A  - no match (no match on A)
```

Full JS example:

```
var re = /[0-1]\d\/[0-3]\d\/\d{4} [0-1]\d:[0-5]\d [AP][M]/; // [aApP][mM] for case insensitive AM/PM
var date = '10/21/2011 06:00 AM';
if (re.test(date) && date.parseExact(date, ['MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt']){
    // date is exact format and valid
}
```

Comment: You need to escape your slashes.

Comment: Thanks, was testing on regexpal.com, added the slashes here for js regex format.

Comment: @Grant You can use this in conjunction with what you have. That would ensure it has the desired format and is a valid date.

Comment: If the am/pm is valid in addition to AM/PM, you can add `i` at the end of the regular express to make it case insensitive. Also updated with an example that uses Date.js to validate the date in addition to the matching the regex.

Comment: Updated with the more strict regex from @Kiyura, currently case sensitive on AM/PM. Use `[aApP][mM]` instead of `[AP][M]` to make it case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks everyone, tomorrow will be significantly less frustrating for me now :)

Answer (score 2):

A stricter regex:

```
/[01]\d\/[0-3]\d\/\d{4} [01]\d:[0-5]\d [AP]M/
```

Comment: Someone mentioned case insensitivity in the other answer; you can change [AP] to [APap] and M to [Mm].

Comment: Ha, what can I say, I steal from the best?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression for the format dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt

```
"[0-3][0-9]\/[0-1][0-9]\/[0-9]{4} [0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] [paPA][Mm]"
```

the above expression works as the below formats

```
01/12/9999 01:00 AM - matches
12/31/9999 01:59 PM - no match
39/19/9999 01:59 PM - matches
39/19/9999 99:99 PM - no match (time out of range)
12/31/9999 99:59 PM - no match (hours out of range)
```